# AngularJS $save form data in a separate hash

Tags: angularjs

Using this setup I can save a form in AngularJS.

I want to have the data values pushed to the server (via the $save method) as defined in the name="" attributes.

So a form submitted like this would look like this:

#### Ideal Form Data

```
{
  book: {
    word : '...',
    book : '...',
    page : '...'
  }
}
```

But instead its being submitted directly as a hash (without the inner book block).

Here's what my form and controller looks like:

#### My Form

```
<div>
  <form data-ng-submit="save()">
    <ol class="fields">
      <li>
        <div class="label">
          <label for="word">Word: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <input type="text" name="word[word]" data-ng-model="word.word" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="label">
          <label for="book">book: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <input type="text" name="word[book]" data-ng-model="word.book" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="label">
          <label for="page">page: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <input type="text" name="word[page]" data-ng-model="word.page" />
        </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <nav class="actions">
      <input type="submit" value="save" />
    </nav>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### My Controller (Angular)

```
var saveCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams, Word, $location) {
  $scope.word = Word.get({
    id : $routeParams.id 
  });
  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.word.$save({
      id : $scope.word.id
    });
    $location.path('/').replace();
  };
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work in your controller:

```
Word.save({
  id : $scope.word.id
}, {
  book : { word: $scope.book }
});
```

Taken from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) I think you need to set the `postData` to override the default data being posted.

> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData,
>   [success], [error])

Comment: Great! Is there any way to make it figure out the model attributes in the form automatically without having to use a selector operation on each of the input elements and match them against the model?

Comment: You can also try { book : $scope.word } to see if that works but I'm thinking it might include the id as well. Maybe you can copy the object and remove the id (something like stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/…) and use the copy in your postData?

Comment: Works only if use a Class.save method instead of instance.$save variable then it works. The default $save() method for an instance won't allow you to set postData so it saves it directly as it is. Who knows if there is a way to override this.

Comment: Can you please edit your response to Class.save(params, postData) instead? The response you have in there is invalid since you can't set postData directly and setting book:$scope.word will set as object if you set it in the hash within the first argument.

Comment: Good catch! I made the change if it's still wrong feel free to modify the answer.